# uninstalling ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, uninstall

I have **ubuntu 12.04.2** along with **windows 7**. I absolutely liked it! But I now want to uninstall this version, reinstall windows 7 and again install ubuntu. How do I remove ubuntu 12 from my system? I have a boot usb from which I installed the software. The **control panel** shows ubuntu installed on the system. I tried removing it from the **add/remove programs**. But it did not work! How do I go about it.?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to remove and reinstall everything?

Answer (score 0):

If your intension is to reinstall windows7 then you can directly do that so that automatically this ubuntu will also be removed while installing a fresh copy of windows7.

But if at all you want to remove ubuntu before you remove windows7, you can do that by simply doing the following steps.
1. Open your system in windows7.
2. Know in which drive you installed Ubuntu
3. Go to that drive and delete all the data related to Ubuntu including Ubuntu installation files completely (shift+delete).
4. Then restart your system and now you would not have two OS' only Windows7 will be present.
5. If you want to use that drive (where you had Ubuntu earlier) to some other purpose us can use it as it is or u can merge it with any other drive (except the drive where you have Windows7) using disk manager which is present in Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Hardware Management >  Disk Management.
6. Be very cautious while merging the drives, otherwise you can end up with data loss.

Comment: Directly removing Ubuntu's partition will also delete Grub (as somoe of its files are installed to Ubuntu's partition) and hence make Windows unbootable.

Comment: I said to delete the Ubuntu files in the partition not the entire partition.

Comment: One could consider Grub or the whole `/boot` folder as "Ubuntu files" and just delete it.